# Chain Lambda Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, cascade, chain

```
public class Translation
{
  public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}            

public class tblEnumJobFunction
{
 public string strEnum { get; set; }          
 public List<Translation> mlgValue { get; set; } //mlgValue->MultiLingualValue
}
```

I have a `List<tblEnumJobFunction> JobFunctionList` with some data.

Example Data:

```
JobFunctionList[0].strEnum="ENUM_Manager";
JobFunctionList[0].mlgValue[0].LanguageCode ="EN";
JobFunctionList[0].mlgValue[0].Value="Manager";

JobFunctionList[0].mlgValue[1].LanguageCode ="DE";
JobFunctionList[0].mlgValue[1].Value="Geschäftsführer";

JobFunctionList[1].strEnum="ENUM_Student";
JobFunctionList[1].mlgValue[0].LanguageCode ="EN";
JobFunctionList[1].mlgValue[0].Value="Student";

JobFunctionList[1].mlgValue[1].LanguageCode ="DE";
JobFunctionList[1].mlgValue[1].Value="Schüler";
```

I can filter this list with LINQ by given country Code and happy with it.

The Question is how can I write equivalent below query syntax by lambda with the List/Collection extensions?

It is a cascade/chain query; looking into a list that is inside another list.

This query syntax is working OK.

```
string CountryCode ="EN"; 
var Query = from jobfunction in JobFunctionList
from translation in jobfunction.mlgValue
 where translation.LanguageCode == CountryCode //'EN'
 select translation;
```

The Result is;

```
List<string> JobList;

foreach (var translationitem in Query)
{
    JobList.Add(translationitem .Value);
}
```

now I have

```
JobList[0]="Manager";
JobList[1]="Student";

For CountryCode="DE" I have;
JobList[0]="Geschäftsführer";
JobList[1]="Schüler";
```

Is there any way to write above query syntax with lambda similiar to this one?

```
JobFunctionList.Select(a=>a.mlgValue).Where(b=>b....)...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `from` clauses, as in your example, flatten your sequence. You need to use `SelectMany` extension method. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
List<string> JobList = Objs.SelectMany(jobFunction => jobFunction.mlgValue)
                           .Where(translation => translation.LanguageCode == CountryCode)
                           .Select(translation => translation.Value)
                           .ToList();
```

*note:* consider using good names, even for formal parameters with the small scope within lambdas . `a`, `b`, `m`, `fo` are not the best names for this.

Comment: It is working Great! Thank you very much! I will follow your reccomendations for the namings as well.

Comment: I follow up your reccomendations with the naming and edited the original question for other people to understand the code better.